# What's the best resolution for the overloaded "select" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Right now [select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) is used for multiple things (and the tag wiki even reflects some of this).

- The POSIX `select()` function (also present in Windows Sockets)
- The SQL `SELECT` keyword (`select-query` tag perhaps)
- jQuery and CSS selector attributes
- The HTML `<select>` tag
- Text/widget selection (focus-related)
- The VB `SELECT CASE` flow control construct (analogous to C-like languages' `switch`)

I haven't specifically seen these usages, but I bet they're out there:

- VHDL `WITH ... SELECT` concurrent assignment construct

Isn't tag overloading considered a "bad thing"? What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Ouch. That's going to take some thinking to sort out...

Comment: I personally don't have a problem with tag overloading, since one can simply search on multiple tags to make the search more specific (as in [this example of sql-select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+select)), but I don't think the community agrees with me.

Comment: Here is `select case`:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select+case

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Those appear to mostly be the SQL `SELECT` keyword, followed by an SQL `CASE` keyword at some other point in the query.

Comment: That would make sense, since it is the only scenario I know of where `select case` is used.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That's a function of your lack of familiarity with VB: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y(v=vs.80).aspx  I did see at least two VBA questions in that list, but most were SQL.  Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145428/vb-net-alternative-to-select-case-when-dealing-with-object-values

Comment: I stand corrected; forgot about VB.  Are you going somewhere with this?

Comment: I don't know.  What was your purpose in linking to the `[select] [case]` search results?  I was just clarifying that said search was pretty durn useless for finding usage of the `SELECT ... CASE` construct.

Comment: My point is that you can achieve the same results searching for two tags as you can insisting on one.  I feel very strongly that this insistence on one tag for every pinpoint concept that the community has been promoting lately is the wrong approach for situations like this.

Comment: So what is the correct search for `select case` then? [tag:select-case] doesn't work, probably because VB (and C# programmers) simply know it as a `case` statement, although [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb+case) doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: There is no correct search (`[vb.net] [case]` and `[vba] [case]` both do better), because the tags are overloaded.  And C# programmers call that `switch`, like C, C++, and Java programmers.  Which I said in my question quite some time ago.  But I don't expect that VB programmers would think to use `switch` as the tag for `SELECT ... CASE` statements.

Comment: I guess all I'm saying is the problem is more complex than you think it is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I didn't say I thought the problem was simple.  And [here's a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679289/how-to-call-a-function-dynamically) where the user isn't calling it a "CASE statement" and the above searches fail.

Comment: In order for more specific tags to solve the problem, they would have to be trivially discoverable and trivially searchable.  A note in the tag wiki for [tag:select] would have to be inserted directing people to use the more specific tags.  I've tried that with [tag:android], directing people to use the more specific [android-intent] tag.  So far, no success, mostly because there are already many questions tagged [android+intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+intent)...

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That's why I came to meta, to get suggestions from the community on what good specific tags would be.

Comment: ...I don't consider this a problem per se, except that the Android community tried to co-opt [tag:intent] to mean only Android Intent, when it actually has more than one meaning.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: we're getting very far afield of the `select` question, but checking the history I can't see your `intent` wiki directing people to `android-intent`.  I suspect however, that rewriting the `intent` wiki and excerpt to emphasize the FORTRAN `INTENT` keyword (and whatever other uses you're aware of) and mentioning the `android-intent` tag should be a start in the right direction.

Comment: Actually, the direction is in the [tag:android] tag.  Apparently I never got around to fixing [tag:intent].

Comment: Also: the [selector] tag.

Answer (score 23):

Here are my tag suggestions:

[posix-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/posix-select) with a [select-posix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-posix) tag synonym, 
[sql-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select) with a [select-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-sql) tag synonym,
[jquery-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-select) with a [select-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-jquery) tag synonym, 
[html-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select) with a [select-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-html) tag synonym...

You get the idea.  The first part of the master tag is the more general term, followed by the term that makes it more specific.  The synonyms are a reverse of the terms, making them more easily discoverable and searchable.

You would have to insert a note into the tag wiki for [select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) to direct people to use the more specific tags.  In the tag wiki body, you can put a list of the alternate tags.

Comment: I still like `select-query` better as the master tag, but this looks like a good approach.

Comment: You can make `select-query` a synonym of `sql-select`.  The specific tags for `sql` become `sql-select`, `sql-from`, `sql-where`, `sql-in`, and so forth.

Comment: To bring more chaos to this, we have now also the [tag:select-function] tag. It's meant to be about the socket `select()` function, but somehow missed e.g. Winsock `select()` function (and all the languages from which can be called).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest we EXTERMINATE!! it for good.

[select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) cannot stand on its own, and therefore should not be a tag. I don't know anyone who's a SQL SELECT expert; same with HTML `<select>` statement.

Comment: Tags are for categorizing subject areas, not expertise.  That some tags like C# attract experts is a happy side-effect.