# Can we [select] better tags for jQuery questions?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The [select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) tag is badly overloaded, as noted in [What's the best resolution for the overloaded "select" tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269214/whats-the-best-resolution-for-the-overloaded-select-tag) .

This is especially problematic in jQuery questions, as some may refer to selecting an element, and some may be about the select HTML element.

Can we please retag all [select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) questions to a less ambiguous tag, at least for jQuery ones, and stop people from using it in new questions, at least for jQuery ones?

Comment: The real question is: do we really need a tag for this?

Comment: @Braiam as a plain text search would get both selecting elements, as well as the select element, I think so. What approach would you take?

Comment: [jquery-selectors] for... well, you know. And IIRC there are tags for some popular plugins that have "select" in their name.

Comment: @BoltClock isn't the existence of plugins with "select" in their name, indicating a overloaded tag, all the more reason to retag?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: Yes, exactly.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289347/215552